# Bolt CMS with load balancing

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm trying to implement Bolt CMS in a setup where servers with content are placed behind load balancer (haproxy). Is it possible to publish content from Bolt to external servers?  Or is there another solution where Bolt can be used in similar setup?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that Bolt itself would be responsible for but it's more than possible. Use a database that supports replication, for Bolt this allows Mysql and Postgres both of these systems allow you to add slaves that will sync the data between the two.

That's the only hard part, in terms of the frontend you can decide your strategy based on load - since the database is normally the bottleneck for quite a while you will often be ok with a single application server and two or more database servers.

You could equally have multiple frontends too each connecting to its own backend database.

Comment: What I'm looking for is two servers with bolt sharing single database and one load balancer (haproxy) in front. I am experimenting with setup similar to this one [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-as-a-layer-4-load-balancer-for-wordpress-application-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04) I managed to get everyting working exept one thing: when I click on 'Preview' I get 'changing ownership not allowed' error when haproxy sends request to second bolt server. Any ideas how to avoid that problem?